# ListView.builder with scrollDirection horizontal got error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => addProductClass()),
            );
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          FutureBuilder(
              future: getDocId(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: dataIDs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return GetProduct(
                      documentId: dataIDs[index],
                    );
                  },
                );
              }),
          Text("text")
        ]));
  }
```

And i want to use `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` for listview. When I insert this value, I got the error:

Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height

Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and '
'constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. '
'In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of '
'vertical space in which to expand

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to provide a fixed height, either using a `SizedBox` or a `ConstrainedBox` with a `maxHeight` set.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **shrinkwrap** to true for listview builder
here is an example of listview builder in horizontal mode :

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return Container( margin: EdgeInsets.all(5), height:10, width:20, color:black);
                    }
                ),
              ),
```

hope it will help !

Comment: I already tried, but this doesn't solve this problem...

Comment: I have update the answer please check now